# Kivy, on_enter method not getting invoked

Tags: python, kivy-language

I have a kivy language file that looks like this.  I have simplified for ease of reading, hopefully there is enough here to get across the concept...

```
<RootScreen>:
    NavigationLayout::
       ScreenManager:
              Screen:
                     ScreenA:
              Screen:
                     ScreenB:
```

The Kivy File for ScreenA:

```
<ProfileScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
```

I have an on_enter method on RootScreen and it is invoked.  However the on_entry methods dont get invoked for ScreenA or ScreenB.

I need to use this method as part of the initialisation of the screen (e.g call REST end point to get data, create widgets for a Scroll region etc.

Any ideas why the on_enter method is not getting invoked on these sub-screens?

Comment: Can you create a minimal running program (.py and .kv files) that shows the behavior?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that the Python classes created for ScreenA and ScreenB where defined as screens:

e.g.

```
class ScreenA(Screen):
```

so the kivy file needed to be changed to:

```
<RootScreen>:
    NavigationLayout::
       ScreenManager:
              ScreenA:
              ScreenB:
```

Once I did that the on_entry method within the ScreenA and ScreenB classes was invoked.